# I am trying to redirect a form after its submitted to a new page based on multiple options picked by the user (Javascript / html)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

*UPDATED*

Thank you I can see there are signs of success as the redirect function works, however it no longer submits the details of the user into my database.
 The code I'm using is below.
The following code shows the original form code without any redirects so you can see how it was uploading into the database prior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://app.greenrope.com/styles/signup.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://app.greenrope.com/img/joinback/design10.css" /> 
<style type="text/css"> .formRow label { font-size: 16px; } #labelFullName { white-space: nowrap; } 
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/app2/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/app2/js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/scripts/signup.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/app2/js/mailcheck.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> Mailcheck.defaultDomains.push('hp.com','yahoo.com.tw','yahoo.com.au','yahoo.com.mx','seznam.cz','bellsouth.net','hotmail.fr','mail.ru','btinternet.com','cox.net','yahoo.com.br','bigpond.com','yahoo.fr','ymail.com','earthlink.net','xtra.co.nz','me.com','yahoo.gr','walla.com','yahoo.es','charter.net','shaw.ca','live.nl','yahoo.ca','orange.fr','optonline.net','gmx.de','wanadoo.fr','optusnet.com.au','rogers.com','web.de','ntlworld.com','juno.com','yahoo.com.sg','rocketmail.com','yandex.ru','yahoo.co.in','centrum.cz','live.co.uk','sympatico.ca','libero.it','walla.co.il','bigpond.net.au','yahoo.com.hk','ig.com.br','live.com.au','free.fr','sky.com','uol.com.br','abv.bg','live.fr','terra.com.br','hotmail.it','tiscali.co.uk','rediffmail.com','aim.com','blueyonder.co.uk','telus.net','bol.com.br','hotmail.es','email.cz','windowslive.com','talktalk.net','home.nl','t-online.de','yahoo.de','telenet.be','163.com','embarqmail.com','windstream.net','roadrunner.com','bluewin.ch','skynet.be','laposte.net','yahoo.it','qq.com','live.dk','planet.nl','hetnet.nl','gmx.net','mindspring.com','rambler.ru','iinet.net.au','eircom.net','yahoo.com.ar','wp.pl','mail.com','emmis.com','hotmail.de','lireo.com','gmx.at','ukr.net','zol.co.zw'); Mailcheck.defaultTopLevelDomains.push('com.au','com.br','ru','us') 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"> function updateConditionals() { if (parent.$('#signupFormIframe3')) { parent.$('#signupFormIframe3').height($('body').height() + 20); } } function checkMandatory() { var ok2submit = 1; var errorFields = ''; var atTest = /\@/; var dotTest = /\./; if ((atTest.test(document.signupForm.Email.value) == false) || (dotTest.test(document.signupForm.Email.value) == false)) { ok2submit = 0; errorFields += 'Email'; } if (document.signupForm.User5.value == '') { ok2submit = 0; errorFields += ', Please select the closest city to where you live from the list'; } if (document.signupForm.Lastname.value == '') { ok2submit = 0; errorFields += ', Lastname'; } if (document.signupForm.Firstname.value == '') { ok2submit = 0; errorFields += ', Firstname'; } if (document.signupForm.User8.value == '') { ok2submit = 0; errorFields += ', Would you like to attend the workshop and/or audition?'; } if (ok2submit == 0) { var errorFields2 = errorFields.replace(/^\, /,''); alert('To submit this form, please ensure you have entered information for: ' + errorFields2); return false; } else { return true; } } $(document).ready(function() { $('#signup_Email').on('blur', function() { $('#emailEntryAlert').html(''); $(this).mailcheck({ suggested: function(element, suggestion) { $('#emailEntryAlert').html('Did you mean <a onclick="$(\'#signup_Email\').val(\'' + suggestion.full + '\'); $(\'#emailEntryAlert\').html(\'\');" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;" title="Click here to make this your intended email address">' + suggestion.full + '</a>?'); }, empty: function(element) { if ($('#signup_Email').val() == '') { $('#emailEntryAlert').html('Be sure to enter a valid email address!'); } } }); }); $(':input').on('click', function () { updateConditionals() }); $(':input').on('blur', function () { updateConditionals() }); $(':input').on('focus', function () { updateConditionals() }); $(':input').on('keyup', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('textarea').on('click', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('textarea').on('blur', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('textarea').on('focus', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('textarea').on('keyup', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('select').on('click', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('select').on('blur', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('select').on('focus', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('select').on('change', function () { updateConditionals() }); updateConditionals(); }); 
</script> 
<style type="text/css"> body, input, select, label, li, p, div, span { font-family: arial; } 
</style> 
<title>Form
</title> 
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="http://app.greenrope.com/users/myteam4/Media1884.ico" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://app.greenrope.com/users/myteam4/Media1884.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="container">
<div id="logoDiv">
</div> 
<div id="formTop">
</div> 
<div id="formContainer"> 
<form name="signupForm" id="signupForm" target="_top" method="post" action="http://app.greenrope.com/j1.pl?9ec6ce8b4e17b30b7c2a75edc1c1a684716721de718b418721aa61ed83378739" onsubmit="return checkMandatory();"> 

<table><tbody>
<tr>
<td> 
<ul id="teamFields"> 
<li class="formRow" id="field_Firstname" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelFirstname" for="signup_Firstname">First Name<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="Firstname" value="" maxlength="64" id="signup_Firstname" class="inputTextField" />
</li> 
<li class="formRow" id="field_Lastname" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelLastname" for="signup_Lastname">Last Name<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="Lastname" value="" maxlength="64" id="signup_Lastname" class="inputTextField" />
</li> 
<li class="formRow emailRow" id="field_Email"><label class="fieldName" for="signup_Email">Email<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="Email" maxlength="64" value="" id="signup_Email" class="inputTextField" />
<div id="emailEntryAlert">
</div>
</li> 
<li class="formRow userFieldName" id="field_User5" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelUser5" for="signup_User5">Please select the closest city to where you live from the list<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label> <select name="User5" id="signup_User5"><option value="">Choose</option> <option value="London" >London</option><option value="Birmingham" >Birmingham</option><option value="Manchester" >Manchester</option></select>
</li> 
<li class="formRow userFieldName" id="field_User8" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelUser8" for="signup_User8">Would you like to attend the workshop and/or audition?<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label> <select name="User8" id="signup_User8"><option value="">Choose</option> <option value="Workshop Only" >Workshop Only</option><option value="Workshop + Audition" >Workshop + Audition</option><option value="Audition Only" >Audition Only</option></select>
</li>
</ul>
<ul id="teamSelection"> 
<li class="formRow joinRow"><span id="confirmText"> </span>
</li> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="4" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="3" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="1" /> 
</ul> 
</td> 
</tr> </tbody>
</table> 
<div id="reqInfo">* required information
</div> 
<input id="formSubmit" type="button"  style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: #000000; border-style: solid; border-width: 8px !important; border-color: #d3d3d3 !important; border-radius: 0px !important; padding: 16px !important; background: #a9a9a9 !important; box-shadow: none !important;" value="Sign Me Up" onClick="return get_action();"/> 
<script>
     function get_action() {

 var optn_value = document.getElementById("signup_User5").value;

        var option_value = document.getElementById("signup_User8").value;


        if ((option_value=="Workshop Only") && (optn_value=="London")) {
            window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuklondonworkshop.html";
     } else if ((option_value=="Workshop Only") && (optn_value=="Birmingham")) {
            window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcukbirminghamworkshop.html";
     } else if ((option_value=="Workshop Only") && (optn_value=="Manchester")) {
            window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcukmanchesterworkshop.html";
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition Only") && (optn_value=="London")) {
            window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-london-audition-confirmation.html";
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition Only") && (optn_value=="Birmingham")) {
            window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-birmingham-audition-confirmation.html";
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition Only") && (optn_value=="Manchester")) {
           document.signupForm.action = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-manchester-audition-confirmation.html"; 
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition + Workshop") && (optn_value=="London")) {
            window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-london-audition-confirmation.html";
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition + Workshop") && (optn_value=="Birmingham")) {
            window.location = "http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-birmingham-audition-confirmation.html";
    } else if ((option_value=="Audition + Workshop") && (optn_value=="Manchester"))
    { window.location ="http://www.mscurvaceousuk.com/mcuk-manchester-audition-confirmation.html"; }   

    }
</script>



<input type="hidden" name="Referrer" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="qstring" value="9ec6ce8b4e17b30b7c2a75edc1c1a684716721de718b418721aa61ed83378739" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="formSubmitCheck" value="1" /> 


</form> 
<div id="formBottom">
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>

</form> 





<div id="formBottom">
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

This was the code before i amended it

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://app.greenrope.com/styles/signup.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://app.greenrope.com/img/joinback/design10.css" /> 
<style type="text/css"> .formRow label { font-size: 16px; } #labelFullName { white-space: nowrap; } 
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/app2/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/app2/js/jquery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/scripts/signup.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://app.greenrope.com/app2/js/mailcheck.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> Mailcheck.defaultDomains.push('hp.com','yahoo.com.tw','yahoo.com.au','yahoo.com.mx','seznam.cz','bellsouth.net','hotmail.fr','mail.ru','btinternet.com','cox.net','yahoo.com.br','bigpond.com','yahoo.fr','ymail.com','earthlink.net','xtra.co.nz','me.com','yahoo.gr','walla.com','yahoo.es','charter.net','shaw.ca','live.nl','yahoo.ca','orange.fr','optonline.net','gmx.de','wanadoo.fr','optusnet.com.au','rogers.com','web.de','ntlworld.com','juno.com','yahoo.com.sg','rocketmail.com','yandex.ru','yahoo.co.in','centrum.cz','live.co.uk','sympatico.ca','libero.it','walla.co.il','bigpond.net.au','yahoo.com.hk','ig.com.br','live.com.au','free.fr','sky.com','uol.com.br','abv.bg','live.fr','terra.com.br','hotmail.it','tiscali.co.uk','rediffmail.com','aim.com','blueyonder.co.uk','telus.net','bol.com.br','hotmail.es','email.cz','windowslive.com','talktalk.net','home.nl','t-online.de','yahoo.de','telenet.be','163.com','embarqmail.com','windstream.net','roadrunner.com','bluewin.ch','skynet.be','laposte.net','yahoo.it','qq.com','live.dk','planet.nl','hetnet.nl','gmx.net','mindspring.com','rambler.ru','iinet.net.au','eircom.net','yahoo.com.ar','wp.pl','mail.com','emmis.com','hotmail.de','lireo.com','gmx.at','ukr.net','zol.co.zw'); Mailcheck.defaultTopLevelDomains.push('com.au','com.br','ru','us') 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"> function updateConditionals() { if (parent.$('#signupFormIframe3')) { parent.$('#signupFormIframe3').height($('body').height() + 20); } } function checkMandatory() { var ok2submit = 1; var errorFields = ''; var atTest = /\@/; var dotTest = /\./; if ((atTest.test(document.signupForm.Email.value) == false) || (dotTest.test(document.signupForm.Email.value) == false)) { ok2submit = 0; errorFields += 'Email'; } if (document.signupForm.User5.value == '') { ok2submit = 0; errorFields += ', Please select the closest city to where you live from the list'; } if (document.signupForm.Lastname.value == '') { ok2submit = 0; errorFields += ', Lastname'; } if (document.signupForm.Firstname.value == '') { ok2submit = 0; errorFields += ', Firstname'; } if (document.signupForm.User8.value == '') { ok2submit = 0; errorFields += ', Would you like to attend the workshop and/or audition?'; } if (ok2submit == 0) { var errorFields2 = errorFields.replace(/^\, /,''); alert('To submit this form, please ensure you have entered information for: ' + errorFields2); return false; } else { return true; } } $(document).ready(function() { $('#signup_Email').on('blur', function() { $('#emailEntryAlert').html(''); $(this).mailcheck({ suggested: function(element, suggestion) { $('#emailEntryAlert').html('Did you mean <a onclick="$(\'#signup_Email\').val(\'' + suggestion.full + '\'); $(\'#emailEntryAlert\').html(\'\');" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;" title="Click here to make this your intended email address">' + suggestion.full + '</a>?'); }, empty: function(element) { if ($('#signup_Email').val() == '') { $('#emailEntryAlert').html('Be sure to enter a valid email address!'); } } }); }); $(':input').on('click', function () { updateConditionals() }); $(':input').on('blur', function () { updateConditionals() }); $(':input').on('focus', function () { updateConditionals() }); $(':input').on('keyup', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('textarea').on('click', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('textarea').on('blur', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('textarea').on('focus', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('textarea').on('keyup', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('select').on('click', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('select').on('blur', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('select').on('focus', function () { updateConditionals() }); $('select').on('change', function () { updateConditionals() }); updateConditionals(); }); 
</script> 
<style type="text/css"> body, input, select, label, li, p, div, span { font-family: arial; } 
</style> 
<title>Form
</title> 
<link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="http://app.greenrope.com/users/myteam4/Media1884.ico" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://app.greenrope.com/users/myteam4/Media1884.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
</head> 
<body> 
<div id="container">
<div id="logoDiv">
</div> 
<div id="formTop">
</div> 
<div id="formContainer"> 
<form name="signupForm" id="signupForm" target="_top" method="post" action="http://app.greenrope.com/j1.pl?9ec6ce8b4e17b30b7c2a75edc1c1a684716721de718b418721aa61ed83378739" onsubmit="return checkMandatory();"> 
<table><tbody>
<tr>
<td> 
<ul id="teamFields"> 
<li class="formRow" id="field_Firstname" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelFirstname" for="signup_Firstname">First Name<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="Firstname" value="" maxlength="64" id="signup_Firstname" class="inputTextField" />
</li> 
<li class="formRow" id="field_Lastname" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelLastname" for="signup_Lastname">Last Name<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="Lastname" value="" maxlength="64" id="signup_Lastname" class="inputTextField" />
</li> 
<li class="formRow emailRow" id="field_Email"><label class="fieldName" for="signup_Email">Email<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label>
<input type="text" name="Email" maxlength="64" value="" id="signup_Email" class="inputTextField" />
<div id="emailEntryAlert">
</div>
</li> 
<li class="formRow userFieldName" id="field_User5" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelUser5" for="signup_User5">Please select the closest city to where you live from the list<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label> <select name="User5" id="signup_User5"><option value="">Choose</option> <option value="London" >London</option><option value="Birmingham" >Birmingham</option><option value="Manchester" >Manchester</option></select>
</li> 
<li class="formRow userFieldName" id="field_User8" ><label class="fieldName" id="labelUser8" for="signup_User8">Would you like to attend the workshop and/or audition?<span class="reqMarker">*</span></label> <select name="User8" id="signup_User8"><option value="">Choose</option> <option value="Workshop Only" >Workshop Only</option><option value="Workshop + Audition" >Workshop + Audition</option><option value="Audition Only" >Audition Only</option></select>
</li>
</ul>
<ul id="teamSelection"> 
<li class="formRow joinRow"><span id="confirmText"> </span>
</li> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="4" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="3" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="AutomaticTeamIDs" value="1" /> 
</ul> 
</td> 
</tr> </tbody>
</table> 
<div id="reqInfo">* required information
</div> 
<input id="formSubmit" type="submit" name="formSubmit" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: #000000; border-style: solid; border-width: 8px !important; border-color: #d3d3d3 !important; border-radius: 0px !important; padding: 16px !important; background: #a9a9a9 !important; box-shadow: none !important;" value="Sign Me Up" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="Referrer" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="qstring" value="9ec6ce8b4e17b30b7c2a75edc1c1a684716721de718b418721aa61ed83378739" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="formSubmitCheck" value="1" /> 
</form> 
<div id="formBottom">
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1. Remove the `onsubmit` function from the Form element.
2. Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`
3. Change the submit button to

   `<input id="formSubmit" type="button" name="formSubmit"  style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: #000000; border-style: solid; border-width: 8px !important; border-color: #d3d3d3 !important; border-radius: 0px !important; padding: 16px !important; background: #a9a9a9 !important; box-shadow: none !important;" value="Sign Me Up" onclick="return get_action();"/>`
4. And in get_action function check for validation:

   `validateForm();`

Comment: Thanks for that, ive amended it and it still gives me the same result. Please can you see amended code above to see if i have missed something?

Comment: thanks alot! However, it no longer submits the user information into my database (crm system) ive put the code im using now in the question along with the original code without the redirect javascript below it.

Comment: please can you advise what i need to put back into the code im using now to get it to store the user info into my crm as it did before.